# Is there any way to inspect an iframe's elements, programatically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

Let's say I have a website's iframe inside my React App.

Is there a way for me to render that iframe with inspect element active and save whatever DOM node I click?

Or anything similar to this?

I haven't been able to find any legit npm packages that do this. Wondering if any of you have ever came across this

For example, something like this
[image]

Except it's in an iframe. The iframe is not of the same-origin

Comment: What do you mean by "with inspect element active"?

Comment: I've updated my description. Not of the same origin, @Spectric

Comment: @Ovi If it's not the same origin, you can't access the DOM because it's protected by the [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Yep you're right. I thought if it's possible to access the DOM of the iframe through the browser's inspector, I could do it programatically as well. Forgot about the same-origin policy. Many thanks